# how to go back to certain previus page jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

im trying to implement a navigation like this using jquery mobile 1.45

page1 -> page2 -> page 3 -> go back to page1

How can i navigate to page1 removing page 3 and page 2 from history?

this is may function:

```
    function backCertainPages(cant) {
      var history = $.mobile.navigate.history.stack;
      history.splice(history.length - cant, cant);
      $.mobile.navigate.history.stack = history;
      $.mobile.back();
}
```

but im getting a

```
Uncaught Exception: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastScroll' of undefined at (compiled_code):6317WL.Logger.__log @ worklight.js:5064WL.Logger.$.each.PUBLIC_API.(anonymous function) @ worklight.js:5444WL.Logger.window.onerror @ worklight.js:5404
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:6317 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastScroll' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

i just put `changeHash: false` in my transitions:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", id, {
        transition : "pop",
        reverse : true,
        role : "back",
        changeHash: false
    });
```

and override all back button logic, except in the first page